# Calculation of an integral from BCS superconducting theory.

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

How do I calculate the following integral?
$$\int_0^{\infty} d z ~z^{1 / 2}\left[\frac{\tanh ((z-1) / 2 t)}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z}\right]=\ln \left(\frac{8 C}{\pi e^2 t}\right),$$
where $C=e^\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

This is the integral in BCS superconducting theory to calculate the transition temperature in 3D space.
Here we may use the residue theorem but I don't know how to process it next.

Further, how do I calculate the 2D space scenario?
$$\int_0^{\infty} d z \left[\frac{\tanh ((z-1) / 2 t)}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z + a}\right],$$
where $a>0$ is a constant.

Comment: It doesn't look like you set up the 2D one correctly, because the integral diverges near $0$.

Comment: Regarding your first integral: the answer is not correct (numeric does not confirm it). Also, I'm not sure that the correct answer can be expressed is in such a simple form.

Answer (score 5):

*Partial solution*

We will evaluate the second integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\tanh \frac{z-1}{ 2 t}}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z + a}\right)dz$$
Splitting the interval of integration
$$I=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\tanh \frac{z-1}{ 2 t}}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z + a}\right)dz+\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tanh \frac z{ 2 t}}{2z}-\frac{1}{2 z + a+2}\right)dz=I_1+I_2\tag{1}$$
Denoting for a while $\alpha=\frac{a+2}{4t}$ and making the substitution $\frac z{2t}=x$
$$I_2=\frac12\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\tanh x}x-\frac1{x+\alpha}\right)dx\tag{2}$$
The integral is well defined for $x\in[0;\infty)$; for the convenience we will consider the integral
$$I(c)=\frac12\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x\tanh x}{x^2+c^2}-\frac{x^2}{(x+\alpha)(x^2+c^2)}\right)dx;\,\,I_2=I(0)\tag{3}$$
Now, let's consider
$$I_A=\int_0^N\frac{x\tanh x}{x^2+c^2}dx=\int_0^{\frac N\pi}\frac{t(\tanh \pi t-1+1)}{t^2+\frac{c^2}{\pi^2}}dt$$
Integrating by part and keeping in mind that we will lead $N\to\infty$
$$=\frac12\ln(t^2+\frac{c^2}{\pi^2})\big(\tanh\pi t-1\big)\,\bigg|_{t=0}^{\frac N\pi}-\frac\pi2\int_0^{\frac N\pi}\frac{\ln(t^2+\frac{c^2}{\pi^2})}{\cosh^2\pi t}dt+\int_0^{\frac N\pi}\frac{tdt}{t^2+\frac{c^2}{\pi^2}}$$
$$=-\frac\pi2\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\big(\frac c\pi-it\big)}{\cosh^2\pi t}dt+\ln N-\ln\pi+O\Big(\frac 1N\Big)$$
To evaluate the remaining integral we go in the complex plane. Noting that
$$\cosh^2\pi(z+i)=\cosh^2z;\,\ln\big(\frac c\pi-iz\big)=\ln\Gamma\big(\frac c\pi-i(z+i)\big)-\ln\Gamma\big(\frac c\pi-iz\big)$$
we can present it as the integral along the rectangular contour $C$ $\,(R\to\infty)\,\,$
$-R\to R\to R+i\to-R+i\to-R$
$$-\frac\pi2\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\big(\frac c\pi-it\big)}{\cosh^2\pi t}dt=\frac\pi2\Re\oint_C\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac c\pi-iz\big)}{\cosh^2\pi z}dz=$$
As we have one double pole at $z=\frac i2$,
$$=\frac\pi2\Re\,2\pi i\underset{z=\frac i2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac c\pi-iz\big)}{\cosh^2\pi z}=-\psi\Big(\frac c\pi+\frac12\Big)$$
$$I_A=\int_0^N\frac{x\tanh x}{x^2+c^2}dx=-\psi\Big(\frac c\pi+\frac12\Big)+\ln N-\ln\pi+O\Big(\frac1N\Big)\tag{4}$$
The evaluation of the second integral in (3) is straightforward and gives
$$I_B=\int_0^N\frac{x^2}{(x+\alpha)(x^2+c^2)}dx=\ln N-\ln\alpha-\frac{c^2}{\alpha^2+c^2}\left(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2c}+\ln\frac c\alpha\right)+O\Big(\frac1N\Big)\tag{5}$$
Putting (4) and (5) into (3), leading $N\to\infty$ and using the explicite value of the digamma function $\psi\big(\frac12\big)=-2\ln2-\gamma$
$$I(c)=\frac{c^2}{2(\alpha^2+c^2)}\left(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2c}+\ln\frac c\alpha\right)+\frac{\ln\frac\alpha\pi}2-\frac{\psi\big(\frac c\pi+\frac12\big)}2$$
$$I_2=I(0)=\frac12\left(\ln\frac\alpha\pi-\psi\Big(\frac12\Big)\right)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{a+2}{\pi t}e^\gamma\right)\tag{6}$$
Evaluation of $I_1$ in (1) is also straightforward and gives
$$I_1=-\frac12\ln\frac{a+2}a+\frac12\int_0^\frac1{2t}\frac{\tanh x}xdx\tag{7}$$
Putting (6) and (7) into (1)
$$\boxed{\,\,I=I_1+I_2=\frac12\ln\left(\frac {ae^\gamma}{\pi t}\right)+\frac12\int_0^\frac1{2t}\frac{\tanh x}xdx\,\,}$$
Quick numeric check confirms the result.